# How to compare text values of two lists of elements in cypress?

Tags: variables, compare, each, cypress, let

I have code like this:

```
let firstUserPrices

cy.get('.fw-price').each($value => {
    firstUserPrices = $value.text()
})

let secondUserPrices
cy.get('.fw-price').each($value => {
    secondUserPrices = $value.text()
    expect(firstUserPrices, 'PRICES').to.equal(secondUserPrices)
})
```

cy.get('.fw-price') has 10 elements and I want to compare all of it one by one. But what i get is 10 times same value with firstUserPrices(it's last value form list) what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, had to put firstUserPrices into an array and push elements to that array

```
let firstUserPrices = []

cy.get('[data-t="my-price"] span span').each($value => {
    firstUserPrices.push($value.text()) 
})

//do some stuff here

cy.get('[data-t="my-price"] span span').each(($value,index) => {
    const secondUserPrices = $value.text()
    expect(firstUserPrices[index], 'PRICES').to.not.equal(secondUserPrices)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this , assuming the length of both lists are equal -

```
cy.get('list1').then((list1) => {
   cy.get('list2').then((list2) => {
      for (var i = 0, i < list1.length, i++) {
         expect(list1.eq(i).text()).to.equal(list2.eq(i).text())
      }
   })
})
```

Comment: When I do this it compare first value of firstUserPrices with all values of secondUserPrices. I want to compare first value of firstUserPrices with first value of secondUserPrices, second value of firstUserPrices with second value of secondUserPrices and so on...

Comment: I added this into variables becouse after firstUserPrices I'm doing some stuff and didn't want to put everything inside that scope

Answer (score 0):

from https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/6.5.0/commands/assertions.html#comparing-arrays

```
const arr = ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Grapes']
// assert that cy.wrap yields the same array reference
// as we passed into it
cy.wrap(arr).should('equal', arr)
// assert the yielded array has the expected items inside
cy.wrap(arr)
  .invoke('reverse')
  .should('deep.equal', ['Grapes', 'Bananas', 'Apples'])
```